# Polymer 1.0 import all elements at once

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have started locking at Googles new Polymer SDK,
now that I started learning I asked my self if it's possible to include all elements of the paper group at once? Otherwise my header gets bigger as my actual body code...

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways that you can achieve this, which can be used in combination with one another.

#### Importing entire element collections

As several commenters have noted, this suggestion no longer works. There is currently [a PR open on the `iron-elements` repository](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-elements/pull/20) that would allow for this functionality. If it's something that you would find useful, then I'd suggest leaving some comment of support (+1).

<s>If, during development and/or prototyping, you would like the convenience and flexibility of having access to all the different `paper-elements` and `iron-elements` at once, the element collection repositories provide a helpful HTML document with all the imports for each of the collections. You can import them like this:</s>

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-elements/iron-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
```

Note that this is typically **not** something you would want to do in a production environment, because it would load many unnecessary imports and waste bandwidth. However, for development, it's convenient as you can easily experiment with new elements without having to add imports for them every time you use one.

#### Externalizing your import code

Because of the fluid nature of HTML imports, you can easily define a second HTML document, just as the Polymer element authors did in the element collections, but for yourself. This file can have a list of all the elements you plan on using. Simply create a document that looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-a11y-keys/iron-a11y-keys.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/some-other-component/some-other-component.html">
```

Then, import it into the pages where you need the elements you've selected:

```
<link rel="import" href="common_elements.html">
```

#### Vulcanizing

Google provides vulcanize, a tool which will parse through your imports and their dependencies and compact them into a single file. Unlike the lists of imports above, this file will actually have the **contents** of the imports, not just a reference to them. This is something you may want to consider when deploying your application to production.

Documentation for vulcanize, as well as the tool itself, is available at https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I will take the first one :D. This was what I'm looking for, but for the future I will keep your tips in mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: hey @Vartan I just saw your Polymer chatroom, I thought this would be nice to discuss there, I believe we learn faster when talking and sharing about the library. so let's get join and rule !

Comment: I wanted to confirm: I don't think the file coming from `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">` has anything nontrivial any longer? It seems to only contain the `bower.json` and `README` files which wouldn't make that `link` tag viable.

Comment: Anyone got this working with Polymer 1.0 ? The two folders for me only contain a readme and a bower.json file.

Comment: @yglodt This answer doesn't work. Con commented this as early as June 14.

Comment: @user568109 It does look like the first option isn't working. Pardon my inattentiveness, haven't been on SO lately. I've updated the answer with a note - it does look like someone has a PR up trying to get that functionality into the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Vulcanize tool to combine all the elements. https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize

Comment: This is a link only answer. Besides how does this answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and as others have pointed out you can make a single import file. I made a script that automates this process and you may be interested aswell as any others who encounter the same problem. It automatically generates an import file from the elements in the working directory. =)

https://gist.github.com/draganmarjanovic/0bef6c298da767bf38b1